# python: why does the program print out the bracket? which i dont think it suppose to

Tags: python, printing

the code is

```
z = 15

print ("answer\t",z)
```

I expect the output to be: `answer    15`, but the actual output is: `('answer\t', 15)`

why would the ()and '' and , in output?

Comment: Seems you are using a Python 2.x version where `print` was a statement (without parentheses) yet.

Comment: You're using Python 2, so you're not printing two items, you're printing a single item (a tuple).  Remove the parentheses to get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove parentheses and it should work. The 2.x version does not require parentheses.

```
z = 15
print "answer\t",z
```